# How can I add font icon in this below code?

Tags: react-redux

How can I add the fort awesome icon in the below code?
I tried add the   icon in the below typeahead. But I need this icon inside the search box. Please help.
I used this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead. Please help with this.

Comment: Simple add cdn in index.html file and use like this
<i className="far fa-user" ></i>

Comment: We are using fortawesome. Already I added in the code <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} /> but it is not coming inside the box

Comment: use <i></i> tag bro

Comment: <InputGroup>
      <InputGroup.Prepend>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} st/>
        </InputGroup.Prepend>

Comment: I tried inputgroup also but it is not coming inside the box

Comment: did you please just used <i className="far fa-user" ></i>

Comment: we are using a unique font style like this <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />. If I add they won't accept in my team. Please help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233429/discussion-between-venusri-and-arslan).